# Example to read and write parquet file using ParquetIO through Apache Beam

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, parquet, apache-beam

Has anybody tried reading/writing Parquet file using Apache Beam. Support is added recently in version 2.5.0, hence not much documentation.

I am trying to read json input file and would like to write to parquet format.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I found the usage in source of ParquetIO. There is typo in usage though. There is extra .(dot) before write.
https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/io/parquet/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/parquet/ParquetIO.java

Answer (score 4):

Add the following dependency as **ParquetIO** in different module.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>;
    <artifactId&gt;beam-sdks-java-io-parquet</artifactId>;
    <version>2.6.0</version>;
</dependency>;
```

//Here is code to read and write....

```
PCollection<JsonObject> input = #Your data
PCollection<GenericRecord> pgr =input.apply("parse json", ParDo.of(new DoFn<JsonObject, GenericRecord> {
        @ProcessElement
        public void processElement(ProcessContext context) {
            JsonObject json= context.getElement();
            GenericRecord record = #convert json to GenericRecord with schema
            context.output(record);
        }
    }));
pgr.apply(FileIO.<GenericRecord>write().via(ParquetIO.sink(schema)).to("path/to/save"));

PCollection<GenericRecord> data = pipeline.apply(
            ParquetIO.read(schema).from("path/to/read"));
```

Answer (score 3):

You will need to use [ParquetIO.Sink](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/2.5.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/parquet/ParquetIO.Sink.html). It implements FileIO.