# how to rea a json data and sava as parquet in apache beam

Tags: json, apache-beam, parquet

This is a problem that has bothered me for two days。

**I can read a json data from local ,but when I write it as parquet get a error.**

my code as following :

```
public class parquet_save_convert {

private static final Schema SCHEMA = new Schema.Parser().parse(
        "{ \n" +
                " \"namespace\": \"com.navteq.avro\", \n" +
                " \"name\": \"FacebookUser\", \n" +
                " \"type\": \"record\",\n" +
                " \"fields\": [\n" +
                " {\"name\": \"event_level\", \"type\": \"string\"},\n" +
                " {\"name\": \"spm_page\", \"type\": \"string\"},\n" +
                " {\"name\": \"spm_module\", \"type\": \"string\"} ]\n" +
                "}");


public static void main(String[] args) {
    Gson gson=new  GsonBuilder().create();
    String outputPath = "./output/parquet";
    PipelineOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory.create();
    Pipeline pipeline = Pipeline.create(options);
    pipeline.apply(TextIO.read().from("./input/event_type.json"))
            .apply(ParDo.of(new DoFn<String,GenericRecord>(){
                @ProcessElement
                public void processElement(ProcessContext c){
                    HashMap<String,String> map= gson.fromJson(c.element().toString(),HashMap.class);

                    GenericRecord osRecord = new GenericData.Record(SCHEMA);

                    map.forEach((k,v)->{
                        osRecord.put(k,v);
                    });

                    c.output(osRecord);
                }
            }))
            .setCoder(AvroCoder.of(GenericRecord.class,SCHEMA))
            .apply(FileIO.<GenericRecord>write()
                    .via(ParquetIO.sink(SCHEMA)).to(outputPath)
                    .withSuffix(".parquet"));
    pipeline.run().waitUntilFinish();}
```

my input data like:

```
{"event_level":"item","spm_page":"Activity","spm_module":"click"}
{"event_level":"page","spm_page":"Activity","spm_module":"action"}
{"event_level":"page","spm_page":"Activity","spm_module":"click"}
{"event_level":"item","spm_page":"Activity","spm_module":"action"}
```

and the exception is :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: unable to serialize DoFnWithExecutionInformation{doFn=parquet_save_convert$1@5d10455d, mainOutputTag=Tag<output>, sideInputMapping={}, schemaInformation=DoFnSchemaInformation{elementConverters=[]}}
```

I also google this problem,but not get a answer ，it makes me feel very frustrated.

[Example to read and write parquet file using ParquetIO through Apache Beam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51168918/example-to-read-and-write-parquet-file-using-parquetio-through-apache-beam)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing your Gson object is not serializable. The solution is probably to initialize this as a local variable in your DoFn's [SetUp](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.4.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/DoFn.Setup.html) method.

Comment: I rewrote the code and the problem was solved。but when i want to save a nested json like "{"event_common"{"timestamp":1596946319063,"spm":"City.PopularActivity_LIST"}}",I get a new prolem as follows:
“Exception in thread "main" org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline$PipelineExecutionException: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to org.apache.avro.generic.IndexedRecord in field event_common”